# Redirect a web link in php using header

Tags: php, html

Help, how to open link like https://www.google.com using php header while code in local server? im using localhost

my php code:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['kirim'])){
        header("Location: https://www.google.com/");
    }
?>
```

my html code:

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                            <button type="submit" name="kirim" class="btn btn-default"><a href="crud/confirm-process.php" style="color:white">Reservation via Whatsapp</a></button>
                        </div>
```

and after i clicked the button always show blank page

[blank page after clicked the button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHzWn.png)

i want open google.com link or whatsapp link after click the button

Comment: Your code contains `if(isset($_GET['kirim']))`...so it'll only set the redirect header if there's a parameter called "kirim" present in the URL. But I can see from your screenshot that there isn't one. On that basis it's unclear why you were expecting it to work. Do understand what the `if(isset($_GET['kirim']))` line means?

Comment: P.s. why have you got a link inside a submit button  in your html? Semantically that makes no sense and it's also redundant. Just use one or the other, whichever is appropriate to the situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the form element of your HTML code you define the action of the data submission. In this case the method is POST and the URL of your action is your PHP file "crud/confirm-process.php":

HTML code

```
<form action='crud/confirm-process.php'  method='POST' >
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
<button type="submit" name="kirim" class="btn btn-default">Reservation via Google</button>
</div>
</form>
```

PHP code in crud/confirm-process.php

```
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['kirim'])){
    header("Location: https://www.google.com/");
 }
?>
```

Comment: You should add a proper explanation